# Rounding to three decimals in Python

Tags: python, text-mining

I have an answer to my code question that asks me to round

Part 1: Write a line of code in the cell below that will display the lexicon-based sentiment polarity score for the following sentence: 'Hiking in the mountains is fun and very relaxing.'

Part 2: What is the lexicon-based sentiment polarity score for the sentence 'Hiking in the mountains is fun and very relaxing.' ? Report your answer **using three decimals** of precision (e.g., 0.321).**

How do I add a rounding function to this in the snippet of code?

```
get_lexicon_polarity('Hiking in the mountains is fun and very relaxing')
```

I know that I can always do this to the answer:

```
np.round(0.2310364009813431, 3)
```

BUT - I would like to know how to call it in the original code.

Comment: Python has a builtin `round()` function, even without using NumPy. But what do you mean by "in the original code"? I'm not sure what your actual question is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 ways here:

1: assign the result of get_lexicon_polarity to a variable, then pass the variable to np.round

```
lexicon_polarity = get_lexicon_polarity('Hiking in the mountains is fun and very relaxing')
np.round(lexicon_polarity, 3)
```

2: pass the function with parameter as an input parameter to np.round

```
np.round(get_lexicon_polarity('Hiking in the mountains is fun and very relaxing'), 3)
```

Comment: I used #2, because lexicon_polarity was already used to define something and that worked perfectly! Thank you!!! I was close but just couldn't figure it out. Coding is definitely bewitching!